# Rpgle data struct prob

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

The chars are I am putting in are as follows:- 

"췡전V" which are UTF16 hex as CDE1C8040056

Some one please help me understand what is going on:-

1) I change my job CCSID to 833

2) Code I run is as follows:-

```
D w_VIN           ds                              
D  vin1                               like(AAF010)
D  vin2                               like(AACDE1)
D  vin3                               like(AAF006)
```

where:- 
AAF010   is a C(10) CCSID(1200), AACDE1   is a C(1)  CCSID(1200) and AAF006            is C(6)

where DataFld C(17)  CCSID(1200)
The code that is executed is :-

```
w_VIN  = dataFld;
```

EVAL datafld:x

```
00000     CDE1C804 00560020 00200020 00200020
00010     00200020 00200020 00200020 00200020
00020     0020.... ........ ........ ........
```

EVAL w_VIN:x

```
00000     0EC2D7B8 E50FE540 40404040 40404040
00010     40404040 40404040 40404040 40404040
00020     4040.... ........ ........ ........
```

I am expecting CDE1C8040056, I really don't understand why, someone please explain? 
How do I get the result I want?

Regards,
Jemrug

Comment: So how do I make sure that the correct values end up in vin1,vin2 & vin3? Is the only way using %subst(datafld,1,10) etc

Comment: move datafld w_vin;    Who knows this is some crazy....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data structures do not have a data type explicitly assigned to them. They are always implicitly fixed char fields using the Job CCSID. So `w_VIN` is `CHAR() CCSID(833)`. Nothing you can do about that. However, the sub-fields can be anything you want, and you can overlay fields on each other to slice and dice the data structure however you want. For example:

```
dcl-ds w_VIN;
  vin1          Like(aaf010);
  vin2          Like(aacde1);
  vin3          Like(aaf006);
  ucs2_VIN      Like(dataFld) Pos(1);
end-ds;
```

Now `w_VIN` is not defined like `dataFld` so a conversion would occur if you did

```
w_VIN = dataFld;
```

`ucs2_VIN` is defined exactly like `dataFld`, and no conversion would occur if you did

```
ucs2_VIN = dataFld;
```

Since `ucs2_VIN` explicitly starts at the first character of the data structure, it will overlay `vin1`, `vin2`, and `vin3`. The sequence of defining these sub-fields matters. If you put `ucs_VIN` first, `vin1`, `vin2`, and `vin3` would follow it in the structure, but since I defined the data structure first, and then added an additional definition at the end, that last definition will be overlaid on top of the other definitions.

Comment: Thank you so so much for making me understand. You have opened up my eyes now.